# Is it reasonable/worth it to try downvoting an accepted answer with numerous votes?

Tags: discussion

I stumbled upon a question relevant to me (about a development environment I'm not very familiar with) and noticed that it's a popular question (common problem), with several answers, the accepted one having over 200 upvotes.

No, the thing is, I believe the answer is totally wrong. I can even back up my position by, well, an ever higher-voted accepted answer to a generalization of the question, here on SO.

Obviously I commented (although I'm not sure the 10th-or-lower comment in a long sequence going off on other tangents). Now, I was about to downvote, and then I thought "Wait a minute, maybe you simply don't belong with this crowd of weirdos who think that X is a reasonable way to do Y? Let them have their own paradigms which they all seem to agree on, and just move on."

Should I put my rep where my mouth is and downvote? Or should I just go away?

**Edit:** Ok, I've been found out, it's:

[Determine if variable is defined in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592565/determine-if-variable-is-defined-in-python/1592578#comment47288728_1592578)

and note it's a very popular dupe of another question with better answers.

Comment: How you vote is completely up to you. No one else can make that choice for you. If you truly feel the answer is incorrect or unhelpful, downvote it or leave it alone. If it's useful, upvote it. Either way, there is no right or wrong answer when it comes to responsibly using your votes.

Comment: Please do downvote if it's incorrect & therefore worthy, and if there are comments going off on other tangents, flag them appropriately as off topic, not constructive, whatever, to get them out of the way of your relevant comment!

Comment: If an answer is not useful, or outright wrong mouse over the down vote triangle for the answer and read the text. Many people appear to upvote everything that appears useful in a question, even if they didn't personally try it to verify it (answer 3 fixed it, upvote everything). Down votes are necessary to help identify what the correct and quality answers are and may also signal to the OP that they should revisit the answer and fix it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: They're on topic, actually, but they assume the answer is valid...

Comment: "Let them have their own paradigms which they all seem to agree on" so the answer wasn't useful to you?  I'd personally downvote then.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Let's say, I think it will be detrimental to other people using/maintaing their code in the future...

Comment: @einpoklum Well I'd then upvote the posts/comments that point out this terrible oversight.  Of course, since you commented there maybe there isn't anything better to upvote... that's a bad situation.  Hopefully enough people will also see the problem you see and upvote relevant comments/posts.

Comment: @ryanyuyu if I looked at the OP's activity recently correctly, the question in question was closed as a duplicate of others some time ago. The accepted answer on the question is... dubious in its correctness (using exceptions as control flow statements).  The accepted answers on the duplicate targets appear to be correct. Thus one can't add a new answer (its closed as a dup) and the other targets don't need a new answer because they are correct already.

Comment: Ah thanks that explains a lot.  @einpoklum If MichaelT is right that the question is closed as a dup then voting on this question is less important.  Random googlers will be automatically redirected to the (correct) question that the duplicate points to.

Comment: @ryanyuyu random googlers are only redirected if there are no answers on the duplicate. If there are answers, they land where they land. And as the duplicate has more views and votes than the targets (even though the targets are more correct)... views and votes will continue to accumulate on the less correct way of doing it (it works) without going to the dup targets.

Comment: @MichaelT Oh no.  That's a _really_ bad situation.  Is there any remedy beyond a bunch of downvotes (perhaps spurred by meta-effect)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu given that the question of the language in question that einpoklum found has a very active chat room, I would suggest for einpoklum to go to that language's chat room and talk about possible solutions there. I also suspect that... given the controversy of this practice in the comments that if it is correct or not is in also in question. A heavy handed approach might be to merge the questions (they are essentially the same). And I stand corrected - one dup target has 40k more views and +200 more on the accepted answer.

Comment: @MichaelT: Yes, you're right. I guess I should have mentioned the question was a dupe of something else.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: ping, MichaelT is right. And - "a bunch" won't do, you need well over 200...

Comment: @einpoklum That's less than ideal.  Well at any rate, 3 dudes just commenting on this post isn't going to solve that problem.  We can either address it as a new post (question), or take MichaelsT advice and bring it up in chat.  If we feel it's a problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Chatting about it is too much commitment for me at this point in life :-(

Comment: @einpoklum same reason I probably won't create a post to solve this problem.

Comment: @einpoklum just calling out the post on meta may be enough for the Python community (now that its been called out) to take note of it and see what can / should be done within the context of Stack Overflow's system. There are things that can be done.  Dropping into [their chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python) and asking about it isn't that much of a commitment. And seeing that you've done this (noted your name in recent chatters) suggests that's the best way to work it out.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Just went to the Python chat room, the guy there who responded and appeared authoritative says this is A-Ok in Python. Weird. My initial dilemma remains.

Comment: @einpoklum I understand your dilemma. Python uses [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp) coding style, where exceptions are indeed used more than conditional expressions.

Answer (score 27):

I didn't play PI on your profile so I'm answering this in general and not to the specific post you're talking about.

I would say yes and you should leave a comment with a link to other post because users who have the ability (through rep or an [app](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)) and check the voting count will take a second look at it. If the current total is 200 but it's from 600 ups and 400 downs, I'd have to ponder or at least search a bit more. The comment is useful for those who can't see the vote counts and the link takes them in the right direction assuming it doesn't die some day.

But ultimately it's up to you. Make yourself happy.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point, actually. Presence of downvotes can be detected regardless of total votes... if you have a bit of reputation anyway. It won't help newbies though.

Comment: Yeah, you can't win them all. Don't forget about the comment that briefly points out why it's wrong with the link to the other. Everyone can see comments and links. @einpoklum

Comment: Right.  This should probably be a new question, but why exactly DO we need a certain amount of rep to be able to see how many upvotes and how many downvotes make up the total?

Comment: @DavidWallace, that is an excellent question. I can't see what deep secrets are revealed by it?? Post a feature-request and you'll get my +1.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Without enough rep (and even without an account), anyone can view these up/down vote counters. See https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep.

Comment: Nice! @RobW. Added a link in the post.

Comment: @DavidWallace For performance reasons.  Apparently it's an expensive query.