# How to deal with peer pressure to change the answer I accepted

Tags: discussion

I ran into a situation where I had marked a question as answered, but another asker wanted me to change my selection to their answer, even though in my opinion, the answer I marked as correct originally was the one that really addressed my issue.  (The poster didn't fix the bug I asked about, but found another separate issue in my code.)  Both answers received an equal number of upvotes.

I politely declined, but was quickly downvoted.  (To be fair, I'm not sure if it was the poster or not.)

How should one go about dealing with peer pressure to change answers...that may be followed with retaliatory downvotes if refused?

Comment: Hmya, this happens.  Do keep in mind that SO was carefully crafted to ensure you can never know that it was actually that specific user that gave the DV.   And you don't know, it may well have been a passer-by that never posted a comment.  It is really rather best to get used to the fact that SO users DV a post for any odd reason.  Just like they upvote without ever explaining why.  It happens.

Comment: Step 1: don't call it peer pressure because that is severely overstating what is happening. A comment and a (possible revenge) downvote are every day business on SO.

Comment: Thank you @Gimby for seeing the situation as it is, and there was no revenge downvote on my part. And thanks Frédéric for your unbiased, unprejudiced, and well considered comments. Sorry that you didn't get to use your pitchfork :)

Comment: @mhawke, no worries, the occasions to use it are not sparse nowadays :)

Comment: If it's any consolation, you get 2 reputation from accepting an answer and lose 2 reputation for having your post downvoted.

Comment: @Gimby I imagine it *felt* like peer pressure to the OP. SO can be a harsh world to some.

Comment: I think the title should be changed to 'change the accepted answer' rather than 'change an answer', it sounds like people are abusing you in the comments to change the code you put in YOUR answer. Just my opinion though.

Comment: I think it's better to have other people check your answer and then decide. However, I don't support what the guy did in this case, it is childish and unacceptable.

Comment: The comment that asked for the acceptance to be changed was extremely mild and polite ... if you feel peer pressure from that, you'll probably need to grow a thicker skin here...

Comment: Deal with it by not caring

Comment: @camden_kid true that, good thing there is meta to act as a safety net :)

Comment: @123 I'm curious whether you feel, having read these answers, that you've actually accepted the answer which solved the problem with your original code. It appears that the answer you accepted was merely addressing a symptom of a larger problem, e.g.: passing the wrong argument to `parseCSV()`. I'm particularly concerned because even though you accepted that answer, you abandoned `parseCSV()`... is that to say that the accepted answer _didn't_ fix your problem?

Comment: @camden_kid If that is what you think, then pfah!  I hereby downvote a post of yours at random unless you recant!  (kidding)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

So, first of all... thank you for **not** pointing out the individual user, and allowing us to discuss the behaviour, and not the user. I've also already cleaned up the question in comments, to stop meta-users finding the problem via your profile.

---

Quite simply, all you should do here is ignore the user, and move on. It's your green tick, to use as you wish. Flag their comments as "not constructive"/ "too chatty", and leave it for a moderator to delete them.

In this situation, the user was *pushy*, but **not** (IMO) rude or abusive; obviously if they were, then use that comment flag type instead.

It's also worthy to note that it's their downvotes to use as they please as well; so unless they persistently target you with downvotes, there's nothing to do here.

Comment: Well, that's too bad. *Puts pitchfork back into shed*

Comment: I think I found the question and corresponding user. I take it you don't want me to post them here now?

Comment: @Magisch: unless you *really* think it'll bring something to the question (given I've deleted the offending comments *already*), I'd rather you didn't.

Comment: it is incorrect to ignore the user completely. [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317150/4279) indicates that the user put some thought into the comment and OP should at least consider the change. The accepted answer is at the very top. Other visitors (not just OP) are affected. It is not too much to ask, to reevaluate the choice (it doesn't mean that OP should what answer is accepted but OP should *consider* changing it).

Comment: -1 because it is my downvote to use, not because I disagree with anything you said of find your answer at all objectionable or sub-par in any way.  This is in fact an exemplary answer!

Comment: @canon: I'm reluctant to post the comment here, because I can only see it devolving the question to being about *whether* the OP should have felt pressured by the comment, rather than the more productive, general, and user-agnostic discussion of *what* a user should do if they feel pressured to accept an answer. If you want to question my deletion of the comment, raise a custom flag on the question, and another moderator will review it.

Comment: @canon: My answer is written in the general sense, rather than being tailored for this *specific* situation, so revealing the particular comment left in this instance isn't relevant for the part of my answer you quote. The devil is *not* in the details; the question *How to deal with peer pressure to change the answer I accepted* is perfectly answerable without any context, as demonstrated in mine and rene's answers.

Comment: @canon: no... I'm saying that people should ignore comments, and walk away from the discussion *once they begin feel peer-pressured to change the accepted answer*. Everyone is different, so everyone will begin to feel pressured at different points of a conversation, but the most important point here is that the checkbox is *completely* the 
OPs choice, and Stack Overflow is very much designed for that; the user should **not**, at any point, feel obligated to choose a particular answers.

Comment: @Matt: I appreciate your efforts to keep this meta question separate from the SO question - that makes sense. However, the comment(s) that you deleted from the original post contain the crux of my argument which distinguished my answer from the accepted one. Furthermore, and I'm not saying that it was you, the comment requesting that the OP consider changing the accepted answer, the central point here, has been removed, or edited (I can't tell as the comments are also removed from my own comment history). Many other comments have been removed. ...

Comment: ... This borders on censorship, and would seem to be contrary to the ideals of SO. If it is your aim to keep the original question independent of the meta question,  why are you effectively censoring the comments on the original question? Surely they were not offensive in any way. I think that you should have let the two questions, i.e. the original SO question and the meta question stand for themselves.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I can't tell if you're being overzealous for humor's sake, but I really dislike the "*Meta effect*". I've seen so many times a user be downvoted into oblivion for something that wasn't really *that bad*. If that happened to me when I made a simple mistake and the "mob mentality" community came in to dole out useless downvote revenge, I would simply leave, because that's no community I want to be a part of. The fact that your two comments about the Meta effect are the most upvoted is actually disappointing, even if they were jokes.

Comment: @Chris, I think you're taking this the wrong way. To me, the "Meta effect" is a lot of extra pairs of eyes on a problem. That doesn't necessarily mean we will *always* pull out the pitchforks and torches, though. Had the questioner posted a link, I for one (and I suppose many others) would have realized the situation did not justify retaliation and would have went my merry way (exactly like what we did when Matt pointed out it wasn't worth it). There are, however, instances of *actual* abuse out there, and I believe our reaction should be unequivocal in those cases.

Answer (score 79):

@123 I am the user that asked you, *once*, to change your accepted answer. For the record I did not down vote your question, perhaps a moderator can check that?

Sorry if you felt harassed; not intended. Perhaps the interplay between me and another user felt like peer pressure to you.

You were (IMO of course) mislead by the other answer. I think that it's fair to point out that the answer you accepted is incorrect and why it's wrong. I note that the detailed comment which explained that has been removed. I referred you to my answer to benefit you.

While correctness of an answer might not be the only factor in choosing to accept it, and it is definitely your choice, in this case you might have been unintentionally mislead by the accepted answer, and now have a sub-optimal and possibly incorrect solution.

That you changed your methodology from downloading and parsing a complete CSV file, which you were *so* close to getting working, to parsing paginated HTML shows that the accepted answer did in fact not help you.

So, sorry again if you feel hassled. It is a part of SO culture, and indeed our industry, to argue one's case, and I think that is fine provided that it is done respectfully and in moderation - as is the case here.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I'm under the impression that debunking a misleading answer and asking to accept another are completely orthogonal. Couldn't you have pointed out the misdirection to the questioner *without* asking them to accept your own answer?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I did point it out, _twice_, and so did another user. Those comments were deleted. Here is the actual comment: "... BTW: You should consider marking this answer as correct as it correctly identified the problem that you had with your original code." It's fair enough, I think, when an incorrect answer is accepted over a clearly correct one.

Comment: IMHO the issue is the mixed message this is sending. It gives the impression that your actions were also performed for the sake of acceptance of your answer, not only for the questioner's best interests. That's why I think keeping the two separate would have been a good idea.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: yes, I can absolutely see that point of view. However, I am not sure what is actually _wrong_ with suggesting that an answer be accepted over another that is _clearly_ wrong. It's not about the points, it's about steering the OP, and other users that might later come along,  towards the correct answer. Anyway, give it a year or so and there will be comments on that question, from other users, telling the OP that they should have accepted another answer.

Comment: @mhawke: ...assuming that anyone actually finds the question and cares. Honestly, I consider the question itself very close to a "typo question" (as the actual cause of the OP's problem had nothing to do with what they're asking about), and I'm almost tempted to vote to close and delete it (along with the answers), as the way the issue was resolved is unlikely to be useful to anyone else in the future. In fact, the currently accepted answer at least does have the virtue of solving the problem the OP *describes*, and which someone else finding the question on Google might actually have.

Comment: @Adriaan with respect, I think Matt has mistakenly removed very important context from this discussion.

Comment: @Adriaan and that was mentioned to avoid the community from attacking the commenter by trying to hide the user's identity.... however the user had identified him/herself already in a very obvious way, so I don't see if that is really as relevant anymore

Comment: ***" It is a part of SO culture, and indeed our industry, to argue one's case"*** Yes it is. But as others have identified, asking the OP to accept your answer is a completely different thing. Don't you think the choice should be theirs own, and that perhaps you may be a little biased? You are welcome to talk about the merits of your own solution, but comparing it with other solutions and asking that it be accepted are crass behaviour.

Comment: @Borodin: Yes, the choice is theirs as I said, clearly right here in this post: **_"and it is definitely your choice"_** - I do think that it is the OP's choice. That doesn't prohibit asking them to _reconsider_ their acceptance of a misleading answer. It was not an order, it was a polite (not _crass_) request, and it's in the interests of the OP, other SO users, and I suppose my biased self in a very minor way:)

Comment: @Borodin: Unfortunately, because many of the comments from the original post have been edited/deleted, it's difficult for late-comers to make effective comments on this issue. I do, however, get your general argument and I could have phrased my request to consider changing the accepted answer in a more subtle way to avoid offense. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

The marker in front of the answer doesn't mean it is the correct answer. It means that the answer worked best for the OP.

Nobody except the OP can decide if an answer works for them. The use of [peer pressure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266962/what-to-do-if-accepted-answer-is-wrong), [voting mob](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289938/is-it-reasonable-worth-it-to-try-downvoting-an-accepted-answer-with-numerous-vot) and/or [moderator flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262672/can-moderators-make-an-answer-accepted-to-close-the-post) are not going to change that because it is the primary responsibility and right for the OP to choose the answer that worked for them.

Users that think otherwise and try to convince the OP choosing something else are wasting their time and that of the OP. If other answers are *better* as judged by the community will get more votes. It is not uncommon for other answers to have a higher score then the accepted answer. That is not bad, it is part of how future visitors can determine the merits of each answer.

You're free to ignore the comments, reply politely with a *No thanks, I'm fine* and maybe point to one or two meta posts on the topic. If the comments get out-of-control flag them for a moderator to look at. Take the down votes for granted. You'll be doing fine in the end.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll mark the first answer that provides a working solution to my problem correct. If a more detailed answer is posted later, I don't think I'm compelled to change my selection.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that reason for accepting an answer. I've certainly had cases where my answer to "X isn't working" was "Here's how you do X" but someone else chimes in with "Don't do X. Do Y instead" and is the other user's answer is accepted because it really was a better solution for the user despite not directly answering the question.

Comment: I would agree with you if accepted answers of other users were not at the very top in each question. If somebody thinks that the accepted answer is incorrect and there is a more sensible solution then OP should be encouraged to change the accepted answer -- it may help future visitors.

Comment: Who do you think you are that you can decide that another answer is more sensible for me?

Comment: @rene: who do _you_ think you are that you can say that I can't have an opinion, and voice it appropriately?

Comment: @mhawke Note that rene didn't say anything about whether you should have commented or not, he just answered the OPs question with the only logical course or action.

Comment: @mhawke sure, you can do that and please keep doing that. I'm only commenting to users that don't add the notion that it still is the right of the OP to mark an answer, despite how wrong it might look like for us. Use all our tools to make that clear but it the end it is still the OP to decide. I defend that responsibility of the OP. That in this specific case it turns out you seem to be called out for a simple nudge of the OP is something I regret. I have no doubt about your good intentions after reading your answer.

Comment: Incorrect answers are accepted all the time... [even on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315750/4639281) :)

Comment: @mhawke do note the typo you made yourself in comment #2 of your own answer. I quote: *"BTW: You should consider marking this answer as correct as it correctly identified the problem that you had with your original code."* . Mark it as **correct** ? No, you mark an answer as **accepted**, a whole different thing. If that typo was communicated verbatim to the OP, then I can imagine things got confusing.

Comment: @Gimby: Thanks, wrong word, but I think that you're splitting hairs; it's obvious what is meant. Regardless of which word was used and any potential confusion, it does not amount to peer pressure. BTW: how did you dig up the comment? - I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: _"It means that the answer worked best for the OP."_ Well, it's _supposed_ to mean that. Given the information provided here and on the posts in question, it doesn't seem like that's actually the case.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, don't get defensive. Anyone can make a mistake. So, take an honest, critical look at the argument. If it has merit, consider changing your vote. If not, just ignore it. If it was abusive in any way, flag it and walk away.

That said, consider the following exchange:

> **OP:** I almost drowned while I was asleep in my bed; there's water everywhere! What happened? How do I fix this? Here's some more info [...]
>
> **Answer 1:** Humans asphyxiate when submerged in water for prolonged periods of time. Make sure to bring oxygen with you for extended periods of submersion. See [SCUBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scuba_set)
>
> **Answer 2:** Uhh... based on what I'm seeing here, your pipes burst while you were asleep. First, let's stop the water. Start by locating your main shut-off valve [...]

That first answer is *correct*, in a sense... but slapping on some SCUBA pajamas before bed only serves to address one symptom of a larger problem. On the other hand, the second answer actually addresses the ultimate cause of the OP's problem in a manner specific to his situation... and it's crucial that the OP understands that distinction.

In this case, the OP decided that the SCUBA answer was the best answer -even while he sat unhappily in his still flooded house. We'd be doing a disservice to the OP by ignoring that he's accepted an answer which may simply conceal his real problem... particularly if there's a more appropriate answer readily available.

Comment: In this case the OP accepted an answer that they honestly thought fixed the problem. Perhaps they accepted it **_too soon_** and dismissed other answers because it superficially solved their problem. That's OK, it's not a disservice to do that, and the OP eventually discovered that it did not actually fix the root problem. But, in this specific case, when the OP realised that it did not fix their problem, they opted for an inferior (IMO) solution, which was unfortunate because they so very nearly had it working in the first place. That's why they were asked to reconsider their accepted answer.

Comment: While it is very interesting to read into how people think this thread very long. It seems that there are very strong views about this topic but, there also comes a point when we should probably admit nobody is perfect and move on. Even processors miss a cycle every few 10's of billions of cycles!!