# Finding a better answer after a while

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette, self-answer

I posted a question 4 months ago, and I got a good answer, which I marked as the correct answer. Now, 4 months later I found by a chance a better solution than the answer I accepted, and I practically changed my project to use the new solution I had found.

Now my problem is:

On the one hand, I got the old answer when my work was stuck and it really helped me when I needed it. Without that answer I couldn't have continued working. I don't think it's fair to take back the reputation-points from the guy who gave me that answer, and it was a pretty good solution.

One the other hand, I found now a better solution which I practically changed my project to use, and I want other programmers who face the same problem to see the better answer. I can add it as another answer or write it in the bottom of my question as an edit, but it's a long question and people who see it probably only read the title and the correct answer.

My question is: [Sharing TypeScript classes between client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796604/sharing-typescript-classes-between-client-and-server)

And my new answer is:

> Before TypeScript 1.4 there where two module loading methods for
>   TypeScript compiler: AMD and CommonJS. In TypeScript 1.4 they added a
>   new type of module loader: UMD, which is designated exactly for my
>   scenario: sharing classes between client and server.
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/07/20/announcing-typescript-1-5/

What should I do?

Comment: Whatever you do, do NOT edit the answer into the question. You also seem to be referring to the *accepted* answer as "the correct answer". There can of course be multiple correct answers on any question, that green checkmark does not imply correctness (as there are also plenty of accepted answers which are actually wrong, a subject of many meta posts). So long story short: post your darned answer. If you change the accepted answer is fully up to you. Its your right to do so.

Comment: @Gimby what should be the accepted answer: the answer I think is the best (even if added a long time after I accepted another answer) or the answer that helped me in real time when I really needed it?

Comment: In short "pick the one that helped you the most", but in practice its not that simple and the subject of numerous meta questions. Here is one for example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317124/how-to-deal-with-peer-pressure-to-change-the-answer-i-accepted - that doesn't directly answer the question but there is a lot of guidance in there on how to rationalise it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, please post this as a new answer (but you might want to elaborate a bit, so that the answer doesn't become useless if the link breaks). There are [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6790067/4751173) [occasions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733753/4751173) where newer versions of technology offer new (and better) possibilities to solve a certain problem. It doesn't matter that this is your *own* question.

In time, you could even accept your own answer, but in your case I would do that once the new TypeScript version is widely in use. Note that as an accepted *self*-answer, it won't be displayed at the top (unless it has the most votes of course).

Comment: TypeScript 1.4 was already widely in use when I accepted the original answer, so I definitely can accept it now. But there is a question about etiquette: If people added & accepted their own answers regularly after they have gotten some experience with a certain technology, on the one hand the accepted answers in Stackoverflow would always be the best ones, but on the other hand people wouldn't have a lot of motivation to answer other people's questions. I don't feel comfortable to undo acceptance of an answer that helped me when I really needed it. – Alon 6 mins ago